# Getting JSON data from a PHP script using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

My PHP script, 'getNews.php', (which works when I run it in the terminal and returns the correct data) is as follows:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=table', 'name', 'password');

$sql = "SELECT * from `news` ORDER BY date";
$result = $db->query($sql);

echo json_encode($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
?>
```

In my Javascript (I have JQuery loaded), I am attempting to pull this data in the following manner:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("getNews.php", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

which does nothing.  When I change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("getNews.php", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

It writes the entire text of the php script to the console.  Basically, it doesn't seem to be executing the php script or retrieving the json object at all.  Thoughts?

Comment: You have a webserver and PHP installed and configured to serve PHP files?

Comment: JSON.parse(data); inside the return function if php is working.

Comment: Your web server isn't properly configured to parse PHP files.

Comment: I think you are confusing apples and oranges. console log the whole php website?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a web server (like [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) or [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx)) installed? "It writes the entire text of the php script to the console." = You aren't invoking a PHP processor.  Are you loading it like `file:///something`, or via `http://something`?

If you are using HTTP, make sure your web server knows to process PHP files. This usually involves editing a .ini or .cfg file; I can't tell which, because you don't mention what web server you are using.

Comment: I am loading it via http://something because with file:///something I get a same origin policy error.  I'm using my school's web server so I'm not actually sure how to modify that.

Comment: Then you may not have PHP hooked up to your webserver.  What happens if you put this in a page and load it? `<?php echo "foo"; ?>`

Comment: Hmm, it seems to just comment out the php.  I will contact somebody to see if I need to configure the site to run php somehow.

Comment: There you go; it's not interpreting the PHP, but is simply serving it up as though it were HTML.

Answer (score 0):

> It writes the entire text of the php script to the console

It could be that your server doesnt have php installed/configured. If thats not the case then see if this works for you

```
function prsJSN() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "getNews.php",
        success: function(json) {
            var dataArray = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could also be missing <?php ?> tags

Comment: @SeñorReginoldFrancis good point. It could be as simple as that, but theyre there in the question